# XsltListViewWebPart Custom Filtering on Query String with paging

Tags: 2013, query, paging

We are working on a solution to use custom query and paging inside a XsltListViewWebPart.

This work,s but the paging does not work:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(((XsltListViewWebPart)part).XmlDefinition);
var queryNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Query");
if (queryNode == null) return;
var whereNode = queryNode.SelectSingleNode("Where");
if (whereNode != null) queryNode.RemoveChild(whereNode);
var newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Where", String.Empty);
newNode.InnerXml = query;
queryNode.AppendChild(newNode);
((XsltListViewWebPart)part).XmlDefinition = doc.OuterXml;
```

We also tried this way for paging:

```
SPDataSource ds = ((XsltListViewWebPart)part).DataSource as SPDataSource;
XmlDocument viewXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
viewXmlDoc.LoadXml(ds.SelectCommand);
XmlNode queryNode = viewXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Query");
queryNode.InnerXml = "<Where><In><FieldRef Name='Assigned_x0020_Employee'/><Values><Value Type='User'>name</Value></Values></In></Where>";
ds.SelectCommand = viewXmlDoc.OuterXml;
```

The problem is that if we click on the paging button to get the next items filtering for a special name all items will be shown and not only further items based on the query string.

Any ideas?